# What is the best time of the year to plant St. Augustine grass plugs?

Tags: grass, lawn-repair

I live in Dallas, Texas. When would you say the best time of year would be to plant [St. Augustine grass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Augustine_Grass) plugs?

Answer (score 2):

Right now is a great time. October through December is best so it can establish before the summer scorch.